# How to include RSpec helper in IRB session?

Tags: rspec, pry

Say I have made a handy dandy helper like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include HandyDandyHelper
end
```

How do I include it in an IRB session?

```
[16] pry(main)> include HandyDandyHelper
NameError: uninitialized constant HandyDandyHelper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to require the file containing the module before including it, so Ruby knows what code you're talking about.

```
require './handy_dandy_helper'
include HandyDandyHelper
```

The path to your helper file is relative to the directory in which you start IRB.